# NTFS Permissions Overhaul

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, ntfs

Essentially I am required to do a complete overhaul on a rather old (and messy) Windows server  NTFS permissions. I have a Powershell script which gives me the information I need for permissions but it turns out many folders and subfolders administrators do not any have permissions over and neither are they the owner of the folder.

My idea was to do a recursive `takeown`and give the administrators group ownership. Then on the top level folder, push out the permissions to all sub folders via the option `Replace all child permission entries with these inheritable object permissions`.

However, even after taking ownership of the folders I don't have permissions over - I still get `access denied` when trying to push down permissions from a higher level. How can I achieve this easily?

**EDIT:**

I'm running:

```
takeown /F FOLDER /a /r /d Y
```

Then from the top folder I am trying to setup permissions, check the box to push out to all subfolders. However, it also seems `takeown` removes permissions and just adds Administrator! I did not think `takeown` touched permissions.

Comment: What are the exact commands you are running?